# What are the options for a French citizen, US-resident to get French medical insurance only applicable to France?

Tags: health-insurance, france

I am French citizen, US-resident and interested to know the option to get French medical insurance only applicable to France. https://www.crystal-finance.com/page/prevoyance-sante-expatrie says:

> Pour continuer à bénéficier de tous les avantages d'une sécurité sociale « à la française » dans son pays d'expatriation et lors de ses déplacements en France et à l'Etranger, l'expatrié a le choix entre 2 solutions :
>
> - Cotiser à la Caisse des Français de l'Etranger (CFE) et prendre en supplément une assurance complémentaire,
> - Souscrire une assurance complète, dite au 1er EUR.

[https://translate.google.com](https://translate.google.com/?sl=fr&tl=en&text=Pour%20continuer%20%C3%A0%20b%C3%A9n%C3%A9ficier%20de%20tous%20les%20avantages%20d%27une%20s%C3%A9curit%C3%A9%20sociale%20%C2%AB%20%C3%A0%20la%20fran%C3%A7aise%20%C2%BB%20dans%20son%20pays%20d%27expatriation%20et%20lors%20de%20ses%20d%C3%A9placements%20en%20France%20et%20%C3%A0%20l%27Etranger%2C%20l%27expatri%C3%A9%20a%20le%20choix%20entre%202%20solutions%20%3A%0A%0ACotiser%20%C3%A0%20la%20Caisse%20des%20Fran%C3%A7ais%20de%20l%27Etranger%20(CFE)%20et%20prendre%20en%20suppl%C3%A9ment%20une%20assurance%20compl%C3%A9mentaire%2C%0ASouscrire%20une%20assurance%20compl%C3%A8te%2C%20dite%20au%201er%20EUR.&op=translate):

> To continue to benefit from all the advantages of “French-style” social security in their country of expatriation and when traveling in France and abroad, the expatriate has the choice between 2 solutions:

- Contribute to the Caisse des Français de l'Etranger (CFE) and take additional insurance,
- Take out full insurance, known as the 1st EUR.

However these two solutions are designed for French citizens seeking medical insurance when traveling in France and abroad.  In my case I only want medical insurance for France.

What are the options for a French citizen, US-resident to get French medical insurance only applicable to France?

Comment: Similar, deleted, question: https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:DREc_7PJfegJ:https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/133768/what-are-the-options-for-a-french-citizen-us-resident-to-get-french-medical-ins+&cd=15&hl=de&ct=clnk&gl=de&client=firefox-b-d

Comment: @BernhardDöbler roomba